# Parsing an XML feed not working

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to parse data from an xml or rss file. It is a bit of a mess. People tell me that its meant to be easy but I am struggling alot.

First I want to get the radio shows news to display on site. I got the rss feeds and api both from an external source and they update the xml content daily and I just need to get the file and save it on my server so I can read off it.
Here is a sample of the rss.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <channel>
        <title>external source</title>
        <link>http://www.externalsource.com/</link>
        <description>external source</description>
        <language>en-us</language>
        <pubDate>Thu, Jun 3 2011 10:23:56 PDT</pubDate>

        <ttl>60</ttl>
        <docs>http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/tech/rss</docs>

        <item>
        <title>08:00 pm</title>
        <link>http://www.externalsource.com</link>
        </item>

      <item>
         <title>- Stephen Ace show</title>
         <link>http://www.externalsource.com/stephen_ace</link>
         <description>Stephens show</description>

      </item>
      <item>
         <title>- Sarah Hardy show</title>
         <link>http://www.externalsource.com/sarah_hardy</link>

     <description> Sarah's first show in her new slot.</description>
      </item>
      <item>

         <title>- Radio 4 evening show</title>
         <link>http://www.externalsource.com/shows/id-453</link>
         <description>Bill Grady is supported by co-host Lenny Hillroy</description>
      </item>
      <item>
         <title>- Kiss music evening show will Sady</title>
         <link>http://www.externalsource.com/shows/id-112</link>

         <description>Sady presents the evening show here at Kiss.</description>
      </item>
         </channel>
```

I save this file as tonight.xml and it updates evening 24 hours from a PHP script which uses fread().

I want to show just the titles of the shows that are playing that evening, nothing else.
I am ok with MySQL but am really not getting this. I am very stuck.
Here is my php

```
<?php

$thexml = simplexml_load_file("tonight.xml");

echo $thexml->getName() . "<br />";

foreach($thexml->children() as $child)
  {
  echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
  }
```

When I test it it does not print the correct values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution using the [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement.xpath) function:

```
$thexml = simplexml_load_file("tonight.xml");

foreach ($thexml->xpath('//item/title') as $title) {
    echo $title, "<br>\n";
}
```

You find more Xpath resources here:

- [What is an excellent XPATH reference for learning correct usage of the syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5372312/367456), PHP uses Xpath 1.0 as of today.

Next to SimpleXML there is also DOMDocument, the big sister of it:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DomDocument();
if ($dom->load('tonight.xml')) {
  $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
  foreach ($xpath->query('//item/title') as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue, "<br>\n";
  }
}
```

That should work

You will get it, just focus on filling in all the gaps you find in your knowledge and you will get there.

Read up on DomDocument and DomXPath in them PHP manual here:

- http://php.net/class.domdocument
- http://php.net/class.domxpath

Comment: hey, yep tried the code you gave and works. will check out DomDoc and XPath. thanks

Comment: really like using xpath think it gives me alot of control over nodes

Comment: @HarryMason: I fixed the links to the resources in the answer and replaced the w3fools link with some more insightful resource we have on site. Xpath is very useful, yes. Take your time to learn it, which best works by playing around with it.

Answer (score 1):

if you watch your `$thexml` content you see the following:

```
print_r( $thexml );
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [title] => external source
    [link] => http://www.externalsource.com/
    [description] => external source
    [language] => en-us
    [pubDate] => Thu, Jun 3 2011 10:23:56 PDT
    [ttl] => 60
    [docs] => http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/tech/rss
    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [title] => 08:00 pm
                    [link] => http://www.externalsource.com
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [title] => - Stephen Ace show
                    [link] => http://www.externalsource.com/stephen_ace
                    [description] => Stephens show
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [title] => - Sarah Hardy show
                    [link] => http://www.externalsource.com/sarah_hardy
                    [description] =>  Sarah's first show in her new slot.
                )

            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [title] => - Radio 4 evening show
                    [link] => http://www.externalsource.com/shows/id-453
                    [description] => Bill Grady is supported by co-host Lenny Hillroy
                )

            [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [title] => - Kiss music evening show will Sady
                    [link] => http://www.externalsource.com/shows/id-112
                    [description] => Sady presents the evening show here at Kiss.
                )

        )

)
```

You can iterate over all elements in your item array like this:

```
foreach( $thexml->item as $item ) {
    echo $item->title;
}
```

Comment: oh i see so point to the item object and then each items title property. thanks like this too but reading up on xpath and want to try and use it more, very flexible